# service that takes xxx.1.2.3.4.theservice.com and resolves to IP 1.2.3.4

Tags: selenium, dns

Does anyone know of a free service that's out there that takes xxx.1.2.3.4.theservice.com and resolves to IP 1.2.3.4?

I need this so that I can launch ec2 boxes and point my selenium test scripts at them. I would just use IPs but I need the subdomains to work. Or is there some alternative way to accomplish the same goal? I don't want to mess with the hosts files on my test computers.

More specifically, I need a dns entry X such that music.X and www.X and mail.X to all resolve to my IP.

Comment: I think you have better luck in getting a good answer to this question if you posted it on serverfault.com

Comment: Yes you are: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/

Comment: in your last sentence, what is 'X' ?  Is the same for each domain host entry ?  Is it actually an IP address, per the subject?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need to do is set up your own internal DNS server.

You can create whatever domains you want, and any systems you point to that server will use the entries you create.